# Browser shortcut keys for placing focus on arbitrary input controls

Tags: firefox, input, navigation, focus, keyboard-shortcuts

When surfing the web, I often find myself having to reach for the mouse to place focus on a particular input control. For example, I might need to click in a text box to enter my log-in information. For reasons of efficiency I would prefer to minimise such mouse usage.

I am aware that one can usually use the 'Tab' key to cycle between such controls, but usually there's a whole bunch of header links that one has to navigate before reaching the control of interest. I'm also aware that some applications (e.g. Gmail) have built-in shortcut keys, however I'm looking for something that will work on generic HTML pages.

Usually, once the first control in a form has focus, it's easy to 'Tab' between the remaining controls in that form before submitting it.

My question: Assuming I'm using Firefox (24.0), is there an existing add-on which will speed up (using keyboard shortcuts) the task of setting focus to an arbitrary input control on the page (e.g. the first text box in a form)?

I imagine that such an add-on would listen for a certain key combination e.g. 'Ctrl-Shift-F', upon which it would display tooltip-like information on each visible input control which specifies the subsequent key (e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c' etc) that will cause the corresponding control/link to be focused.

Does anybody know of such an add-on, or am I perhaps looking at this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only tried [Fox Input](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fox-input/), but it's working for me so far. It defaults to `Alt-I` to move forward through text fields and `Alt-J` to move backwards, but you can change the hotkeys in the prefs.

I also use [**VimFX**](https://github.com/akhodakivskiy/VimFx), which can do a tooltip-style selection of links and text fields, but its other features might be overkill for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling into this in 2023, the best solution I've found, and supports both Chrome and Firefox, is [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io/).

> Vimium is a browser extension which provides keyboard shortcuts for navigation and control in the spirit of the Vim editor.
>
> — https://vimium.github.io/

Once installed, restart the browser or refresh your tabs, and then you can press the `f` key to seek and focus/click input elements and links.

Below is how it looks when I push `f` right now. Then following the hints, I could push `F`, `A` to search, or `A`, `M` to post this answer.

[image: Stack Overflow page with Vimium hints displayed over all links and input fields to press via keyboard keys.]